# Database file rename and echo its result in JSON

Tags: php, json

I want to upload a image to a database and rename it and then return the new image name in JSON Format.This is my code:

```
     <?php

    if (isset($_POST['upload_Btn'])) {
        $ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['gambar']['name'])));
        $target = "uploaddosen/". microtime() .".".$ext;


        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'],$target)) {
            $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        }else{
            $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }

      echo $msg;
  }

?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to have the renamed image file return in JSON format so that i can use it to insert the data to a database along with other variables.The renamed image file will be in JSON Format so that it can be used in another php script to insert the renamed JSON file along with the other data to a database.

Comment: You can store image file name in database. You can't store whole file object in db

Comment: Well,i got asked to do so by my employer and basically asked to make 2 PHP Script,1 to ONLY save the image file to a selected folder and then rename the image name before saving it and convert the name into JSON format,then make another PHP Script to input the other data along with the JSON containing the renamed image filename.He said it has to be done as android cant process image upload and text format at the same time according to him.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this way,

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['upload_Btn'])) {
    $ext = end((explode(".", $_FILES['gambar']['name'])));
    $file_name = microtime() .".".$ext;
    $target = "uploaddosen/". microtime() .".".$ext;


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'],$target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        // Write your db insert code here
        echo json_encode(array('msg' => $msg, 'image' => $file_name));
       exit();

    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }

  echo $msg;
```

}

?>